# Devote Entire Disc To Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning

I would like to erase Windows XP partition and devote entire disc space to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS . Currently have 45GB partitioned to Ubuntu and 35 to Windows XP. Can this be done without reinstalling everything from scratch? Thanks.